# BEGIN and END blocks in awk

Tags: awk

I am using the awk command in terminal on my Mac.
I want to print the contents of an already existing file and give a title to each column which i'll separate using a tab then I want to send the output to another file. What line of code would I use to give titles to the columns? Im hoping to use simple awk commands and preferably if I can complete the task in as little lines as possible.

So far I have tried to use the BEGIN command. (The titles I want to give are first name, second name and score)

```
BEGIN { print "First Name\tSecond Name\tScore}**
```

then I want to print the entire contents of the file.

```
{print} filename.txt
```

Finally I want to save the output to another file

```
End{print} filename.txt > output.txt
```

to do this all all together

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "First Name\tSecond Name\tScore";}
{print} 
End{print}' filename.txt > output.txt
```

However, this only saved the titles to the output file and not the contents of the original file under the columns.

Comment: Please don't spam irrelevant tags. What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: `End` != `END` and the output of `END{print}` would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` processes files line by line. Before it starts processing the file you can have it do something. We use the `BEGIN` keyword to note that the following block of code is to be executed before processing. Same with `END` running after the processing of each line of the file is complete.

While your code has some superfluous bits in it, like the unnecessary `END` block, it still should do exactly what you are wanting to do, assuming you have data in your `filename.txt`.

A more succinct `awk` code would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "First Name\tSecond Name\tScore";}1' filename.txt > output.txt
```

In action (using commas instead of tabs because it's easier and I'm lazy):

```
$ echo "1,2,3" > filename.txt
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "c1,c2,c3"}1' filename.txt > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
c1,c2,c3
1,2,3
```

Comment: In this line of code:          awk 'BEGIN {print "c1,c2,c3"}1' filename.txt > output.txt     What is the significant of the '1'?

Comment: It's shorthand. In `awk` you can precede a block with a conditional statement. If the condition is true, then it executes the block. The default execution step is `print $0` so we just say "true" or `1` and it prints the line automatically.